# How to append html inside iframe form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If i have an iframe that has the following structure

```
<iframe id="iframesitefileupload" src="IframeTest.aspx" style="margin-left:20px" name="iframesitefileupload">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" action="IframeTest.aspx" method="post" name="form1">

                 //add stuff here ----                      

            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

How can i append contents to the form element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get access a iframe with .contents():

```
$('#iframesitefileupload').contents().find('#form1')
                          .append('<div>Hello iframe</div>');
```

Answer (score -1):

`IframeTest.aspx` generates the iframe content, why don't you do it there?