# displaying html in div or iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to display my html string in this iFrame.
Actually I am confused whether it should be displayed in iFrame or Div.

***Code:***

```
$("body").append("\
                    <div id='wikiframe'>\
                    <div id='wikiframe_veil' style=''>\
                    <p>Loading...</p>\
                    </div>\
                    <iframe id='wikiIDframe'></iframe>\
                    </div>"
                );
```

I want to display HTML which is in a string `s="<body>....</body>`
In this iFrame how do I Do it. Could any body help me with that.

Comment: [You may find this post helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603900/how-to-append-html-inside-iframe-form-element)

Comment: You will have to load the iframe with src or document.write into the ifram

Comment: Could you tell me the code for the same @mplungjan

Comment: @Pete : my iframe doesn't have anything to be find() to append the content

Comment: If it is in a string, why not remove the body tags and just show it in the div?

Comment: @mplungjan : Little newbie to this stuff. Could you suggest the code-changes..?? Thanks and yes I can remove the body tags..!!

Comment: @rahul888 all iframes should have a body tag - see my answer below

Comment: @rahul888 see if my answer can help you. No JQuery at all, but works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can append your string `s` to your iframe by doing the following:

**jQuery**

```
var s = '<body><div>hello</div></body>';             // example s string
var textBody = $(s);                                 // make s into jquery object
var iframeBody = $('#wikiIDframe').contents().find('body'); // get the body from the iframe

iframeBody.append(textBody.html());                  //append s html into iframe
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4W95y/)

Comment: your answer looks promising. Your fiddle works as I want it exactly. however I can't figure out why my original fiddle isn't working even after including your code changes..!! could you please help me sort out the problem . I would be more than thankful to you and accept your answer. :) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37WRC/1/)

Comment: @rahul888, your code is working - just your styles for the wikiframe  is hiding it somewhere - I removed the styles from your js and it shows up: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/37WRC/5/

Comment: yes I managed to figure that out yesterday..!! but I have got one problem ..!! It displays this page very easily as it's small. But it cannot display if my html string is an entire full fledged web page..!!

Comment: What creates the string `s`? is it pulled from a document?

Comment: yes I get the string from the html document on which I execute this script.

Comment: could you not just change the src of the iframe to point at that document instead of trying to inject the document into it?

Comment: No there are multiple strings on the page that contains this html code's all at seperate parts of the page . Thats why I am extracting .

Comment: Could you insert each part as you extract it then?  that way your not trying to insert too much at any one time

Answer (score 0):

An iframe is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.Which means if you want see a webpage inside a webpage, u can use iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```

see this example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

If you want to display your text then use a div instead.In jquery you can use it like the below code

```
$("#your_div_id").html("yourstring here");
```

Comment: I want to display a html string as a webpage, i.e I have a proper webpage in a `var s="<body> to </body>"` I want this string to displayed as a web page in the iframe.

Comment: make another web page using your codem then point that page to this iframe,else there is no need of iframe, just include the code inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone thought about this?

HTML

```
<iframe id="iframe" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></iframe>
```

JS

```
var myHTML = "<div id='wikiframe'><div id='wikiframe_veil' style=''><p>Loading...</p></div><iframe id='wikiIDframe'></iframe></div>";
document.getElementById('iframe').src = 'data:text/html,<html><body>' + myHTML + '</body></html>';
```

Try it on http://jsfiddle.net/Kqd8R/1/